# I am Making A quiz using PHP & MySql i want to

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a quiz using MYSQL 
Now i Want following functions to be performed

1--> There are 250 questions in my DB but i want to stop query after 50 questions.(Selecting one at a time)

2--> I want to add button Check Correct Answers after clicking on that button user can see "Correct" & "Wrong" under his answers.

Please help me out

My Code for Quiz Asking

```
    <html>
<title>Quiz</title>
<body bgcolor="#666666"> </body>
<h1><center> Quiz </center></h1>
<?php
echo "Welcome Student";
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";
?>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
$dataselect = mysql_select_db("quiz",$con);
if(!$dataselect)
{
die("Database namelist not selected".mysql_error());
}
?>
$query = "SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error processing query. ".mysql_error());
echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'submit.php'>";
echo "<table border = '1'>";
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "".$data['Question']."<br>";
        echo "<input type = 'radio' name='radio' value='Option1'>";
        echo "".$data['Option1']."<br>";
        echo "<input type = 'radio' name='radio' value='Option2'>";
        echo "".$data['Option2']."<br>";
        echo "<input type = 'radio' name='radio' value='Option3'>";
        echo "".$data['Option3']."<br>";
}
echo "<tr><td align = 'center'><input type = 'submit' name = 'go' value = 'GO'></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

In The Above Code User Is Being Asked one question at a time selected randomly from DB & Than This Code Stores His Answer Into DB

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Error connection. ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("quiz", $connection) or die("Error selecting db. ".mysql_error());
$Option['Option1'] = false;
$Option['Option2'] = false;
$Option['Option3'] = false;
$Option[$_POST['radio']] = true;
 $order= "INSERT INTO radio (Option1,Option2,Option3) VALUES ('".$Option['Option1']."','".$Option['Option2']."','".$Option['Option3']."')";
  $result=mysql_query($order) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<html>
<title>Answer Submission</title>
<body bgcolor="#666666"></body>
<center><b><h2>Your Answer Has Been Submitted Successfully Please Click On NEXT To Move Towards Next Question"</h2><br>
<br>
<br>

 <button onClick="window.location.href='Quiz.php'"><center><h3>NEXT</h3></center></button>
 <center><b><h2>Your Answer Has Been Submitted Successfully Please Click On Result To Get Your Results Till Yet"</h2><br>
  <button onClick="window.location.href='studresult.html'"><center><h3>NEXT</h3></center></button>
 </html>
```

But i don't know how to put restriction on query that it stops after 50 questions :/

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Could you add your code to the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We are happy to help you fix problems in your code, but this site is not designed to encourage others to write your code or development plan for you. Please feel free to improve this question or ask a new one when you have a specific, code-related problem.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com - 

Stackoverflow is great to get help with specific problems, but we're not going to do your work for you. Try some ideas in code, then come back if you've got problems with specific bits.

Comment: k let me edit question

Comment: @Ed Gibbs, Nanne, Rick Kuipers,  George Cummins & N.B.can you please unlock the questions :/

Comment: "Now i Want following functions to be performed" - I think this is too broad for here, and I think the down-votes reinforce that conclusion. In general, it is better for you to make an attempt at a question, and then ask here about specific problems. To select 50 random questions from 250, maybe you could select 50 random integers from 1-250, and then store that in a session variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: please be aware that your code is wide open to SQL Injection! You should sanitize the user input.

If you want to remember how many questions the user has already answered, you need to store that information somewhere. If your users have no accounts on the page, there is no secure way to do this, you need you store this client side – and so the user can trick you by just using a second browser.

One way of doing this is the session library of PHP (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php); whenever the user answers a question you increase his session counter by one:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['questions_answered'])) {
  $_SESSION['questions_answered'] = 1;
} else {
  $_SESSION['questions_answered']++;
}
```

And before you ask a question you check the counter:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['questions_answered']) && $_SESSION['questions_answered'] >= 50) {
    echo 'You have already answered 50 questions';
} else {
    // ask him a question
}
```

To show the user his score, you should store his session id (`session_id()`) in the DB together with his answers. When the user clicks the check-button you query the DB for his answers, check them and show the result.

To store the session ID in the DB you should add another column, e.g. `userSessionId` to the table. When you insert the data, you just add the user's session ID to the query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO
        radio (questionId, userSessionId, Option1, Option2, Option3)
    VALUES (
        ".$questionId.",
        ".session_id().",
        '".$Option['Option1']."',
        '".$Option['Option2']."',
        '".$Option['Option3']."')";
```

Additionally you should work with a question ID and store it with the answer, otherwise you won't be able to check the answer...

Comment: Now All I Want Is How To Show His Answers using Session thingy (Because i think using Session will show only his answers not all of them) & otherone how to show him that his answers were correct or wrong

Comment: How to store his session ID. Sorry i did not get your point @Beat :/

Comment: @newbie: I've added the query to show you how to store it

Comment: Ok it's working Correctly but here is the code once again "$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radio where user='session_id()'", $con);" but it returned nothing :(

Comment: Thanks i was writing the select query in a lil wrong way. I solved that. Thanks a lot for your time dude :)

Comment: For Others Correct Query Is "$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radio where user='".session_id()."'", $con);"

Comment: Great, I'm happy it finally works

Comment: Thanks again dude ^_^ You were really helpful can you visit my another question.i am sure you can help me with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822952/storing-data-in-arranged-sequence-into-mysql