# Storing data, in arranged sequence into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I asked random question to student & stored his answers using his session id into mysql & than extracted the same way. 
I used Order By RAND() function in my query while asking the question

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1";
```

But Now I Want to Store answers in an arranged sequence for such purpose i can use Q_ID but i don't want to show q_id to user. So how can i store q_id into another table without showing it to user.
Secondly i want to show correct answers to my students too.

but i really don't know how to tackle these thing :(

query for storing answers

```
$order= "INSERT INTO radio (Option1,Option2,Option3,user) VALUES ('".$Option['Option1']."','".$Option['Option2']."','".$Option['Option3']."','".session_id()."')";
```

Query For Extracting Data From mysql

```
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radio where user='".session_id()."'", $con);
```

Comment: "One More thing regarding my quiz" is not a very descriptive title.

Comment: @George Cummins i am new @ stackoverflow.com i am sorry for inconvience i am creating for you guyz. But i hope i will improve with every next min i spend around :)

Comment: It appears as you split your whole application into multiple questions and let everything be written by Stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your actual database schema/more information it is difficult to give you the best advice possible.

Add a field to the table radio so that it looks something like this:

```
RADIO (*user*, *questionId*, Option1, Option2, Option3)
```

(due to stack overflow formatting stars represent the primary key(s))

where questionID is a foreign key that references QUESTION(id). If you don't have an id field in your question table add that too.

Then when you display the question to the user, save the question ID as a hidden input field inside the  tag like so:

```
<input type='hidden' name='questionId' value='".$data['id']."' />
```

When the form is submitted you will have the question ID available in your $_POST array at `$_POST['questionId']`

Then you can modify your INSERT query to insert the question ID as well and simply not display it when you display the data later.

--

As for displaying the correct answers to the students, you will need to store the correct answer in your table somehow. One way would be to add a field to your question table indicating which of the options is the correct answer, I.E. a TINYINT(1) which will contain a 1, 2, or 3 depending on which answer is correct. You can then use that to generate a page with the correct answer to the question.

Comment: it worked Perfectly Thanks Dude. for Other's Help "echo "<input type='hidden' name='questionId' value='".$data['ID']."/>";"

Comment: Now i need help regarding showing answers. But let me tell the sceniro of DB. It's Storing answers as 1 like if user choosed Option B then in Column Option B query will store 1. But I want to Show Answers Like               Question=...... Option1=..... Option2=....... Option3=..... You Choosed=Option2=..... But Correct Answer=OptionC.....

Comment: I'm going to assume you want to show all of the questions on one page. The query to do this would be

SELECT * FROM Question
LEFT OUTER JOIN Radio
ON Radio.questionId = Question.id
ORDER BY Question.id

This will return a row for each question containing the following variables:
The question ID
The question
Answer Choice 1
Answer Choice 2
Answer Choice 3
The correct answer (see the second part of my comment above)
A second copy of the question ID
What the user entered for each of the answer choices.

You can then process these rows in a loop to print out each question and format it as you wish

Comment: Thanks Mate. It looks like i need to add correct answer field too in my DB. Plus this query (SELECT  FROM Question LEFT OUTER JOIN Radio ON q_id= ID ORDER BY q_id ) works fine But i want to show only not null value. this joins shows everything Even the questions that was not asked from user + i have to add session id as well

Comment: If you only want to show questions for which the user has answered use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN. Left outer join selects all rows in the first (question) table and matching rows in the second (radio). An inner join will only select rows in which there are matching rows in both tables. Adding a WHERE clause before the ORDER BY will help you filter it based on the user.

Comment: hmmm it's not what i wanted. in mysql it's working fine & giving me desired result but with PHP it do not here is the query"$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM radio INNER JOIN question ON q_id= ID ORDER BY ID AND user='".session_id()."'", $con);" & it shows result like "Option A=A: World Wide Web
Option B=B: World Wide Worker
Option C=C: World Wide Wrestling" look it does not showed which was user's choice :/